# Form validation

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, contact-us

In magento how to give validation to telephone field in contact us page

telephone field should accept only numbers and - symbol other should not accept
similarly name field should not allow special character and white space

Answer (score 3):

To validate an input fiel, you just need a `varienForm`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var loginForm = new varienForm('loginForm');
</script>
```

This form registers on the submit event of the `<form>`. Then you just need to add the `validate-` class you want to use, have a look into `Validation.addAllThese()` in `/js/prototype/validation.js:414` or [into the great article fishpig wrote](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/javascript-prototype-form-validation/).

Comment: I have already used this two validate-number( Please enter a valid number in this field)validate-phoneStrict
Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890)            but my need is it should accept num like 1234566778 or (123)-23456 or 123-4567 or +54534343434

Answer (score 2):

Inchoo wrote a great article about form validation that you can read [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/).

On the frontend you can add a class to the input, for example `validate-phoneLax`. In the controller receiving the post values you can use Zend validation like, for example,

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($postdata['telephone'], 'NotEmpty')) {
   $errors[] = $helper->__('Please enter a phone number');
}
```